# How to programmatically add more variables in Magento's WYSIWYG editor

Tags: magento, tinymce, wysiwyg, magento-1.8, transactional-email

I want to add custom variables to "Insert Variable" popup of Magento's WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE)

Searched the internet but couldn't find any solution, is that possible? Any one?

[image: Insert Variable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom variable in your Magento backend:

```
System -> Custom Variable -> Add New Variable
```

Here you can add a HTML or plain text variable.

Variable code is identifier.
Variable name what will be displayed.

For adding custom variables programmatically, see this blog:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/injecting-variables-into-a-magento-cms-static-block/

Comment: Actually I want to programatically add new variables via my custom module.

Comment: I follow those instructions but not worked for me, I am inserting {{var customer_email}} in CMS pages and Blocks but its not rendering to current user email. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below.

Add field in the custom module Form
app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Template\Email\Edit\Tabs\Form.php

```
$editor = Mage::getSingleton('namespace/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('tab_id' => $this->getTabId()));

$fieldset->addField('body', 'editor', array(
    'name' => 'body',
    'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Body'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Body'),
    'style' => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
    'config' => $editor,
    'wysiwyg' => true,
    'required' => true,
));
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Model\Wysiwyg\Config.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Wysiwyg_Config extends Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config
{
    /**
     *
     * @param Varien_Object
     * @return Varien_Object
     */
    public function getConfig($data = array())
    {
        $config = parent::getConfig($data);

        $newOptiones = Mage::getSingleton('namespace/variables_options')->getWysiwygPluginSettings($config);

        if (isset($newOptiones['plugins'][1]) && is_array($newOptiones['plugins'][1])) {
            $config->setData('plugins', array($newOptiones['plugins'][1]));
        }

        $config->setData('files_browser_window_url', Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/'));
        $config->setData('directives_url', Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive'));
        $config->setData('directives_url_quoted', preg_quote($config->getData('directives_url')));
        $config->setData('widget_window_url', Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/widget/index'));
        $config->setData('add_variables', true);

        return $config;
    }

}
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Adminhtml\VariableController.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Adminhtml_VariableController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * WYSIWYG Plugin Action
     *
     */
    public function wysiwygPluginAction()
    {
        $customVariables = Mage::getModel('namespace/variables_process')->getVariablesOptionArray(true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($customVariables));
    }    
}
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Module\Model\Variables\Process.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Variables_Process extends Mage_Core_Model_Variable
{

    public function getVariablesOptionArray($withGroup = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();/*Custom Module Collection*/
        $variables = array();
        foreach ($collection->toOptionArray() as $variable) {
            $variables[] = array(
                'value' => '{{customVar code=' . $variable['value'] . '}}',
                'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('%s', $variable['label'])
            );
        }
        if ($withGroup && $variables) {
            $variables = array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Custom Variables'),
                'value' => $variables
            );
        }


        $allVars = array(
            $variables
        );

        return $allVars;
    }

}
```